# Need example for Posting Core Data objects in JSON to RESTful web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I've been reading over code samples and posts for days but I haven't found a definitive way to post JSON data from my Core Data objects to a RESTful web service.  There's a TON of documentation about pulling the JSON from a web service but not so much about sending stuff back.  Can anyone point me to a good example or post some code on how to do it?  I'm using Core Data and I have the object I want to send back mapped to a Dictionary but I'm missing the code to send it to the service.

EDIT:

I ended up with the code below which looks right and runs without errors, but I get 0 bytes of data returned and my webservice doesn't seem to be receiving the request.  The JSON data looks good, the URL is correct, and I can hit the webservice and get JSON data back from it.  The NSURLConnection delegate methods also fire as expected.

Is there anything I'm missing below?

```
- (void)SubmitSystems
{
    NSFetchRequest * allSystems = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [allSystems setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"System" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSArray * systems = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:allSystems error:&error];

    //error handling goes here
    //for (NSManagedObject * system in systems) {


    NSManagedObject *system = systems[2];

    NSString *entityString = @"System";
    NSString * serverString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kWebServiceAddress, entityString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverString];
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self jsonSystemDictionary:(System *)system] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); //debug only

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval: 30.f];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    self.urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 

//}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to `NSMutableURLRequest`. Using this, you can use `setHTTPMethod` and pass it the `@"POST"` string, and then use the attributes of your `NSManagedObject` to populate the `URL`, `HTTPBody` and/or `HTTPHeader` as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I've come up with some code and updated my post with it.  It seems to run fine but I get 0 bytes of data returned and my web service (.NET WebAPI) doesn't seem to receive the request.

Comment: Is your JSON object being turned into NSData successfully (i.e. is jsonData nil?)?

Comment: It was a URL error from when I switched to a local machine from the prod web service.  The above code is working fine.  Sometimes you can check a thing 20 times and not see an obvious error.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to send many instances of a managed object to a web service?  When my code above: "for (NSManagedObject * system in systems) {"  is uncommented it will be sending up to a thousand instances of the "System" class and I think my existing code will try and spawn many threads to get it done.

Comment: If you check out the AFNetworking library, there is a method for sending batches of HTTP Requests